# How to extend UrlGenerator to generate links with trailing slashes?

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5.1

I've modified the htaccess file to force the trailing slash and would now like any url generation within Laravel to automatically add the slash so we don't have so many redirects.

```
# Force trailing slash.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I then created a CustomUrlGenerator class which extends Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator and I am trying to override the `toRoute` function...

```
protected function toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute)
{
    $route = parent::toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);

    return $route . '/';
}
```

and in `AppServiceProvider.php`, I've added the following code...

```
$this->app->bind('url', function($app) {
    return new CustomUrlGenerator($app['routes']->getBindings(), request());
});
```

Unfortunately, I think this is breaking the app somehow because whenever I try to use anything which uses this function, it can not find the routes, probably because I'm setting this up too early in the life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code in github, `toRoute` is `protected`, meaning that you can't override it as `public`, change your code as follows:

```
protected function toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute)
{
    $route = parent::toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);

    return $route . '/';
}
```

Comment: Good catch, it should in fact be protected but I believe as far as PHP is concerned, increasing the access specifier is allowed.  I've updated the original question.

Comment: increasing yes, decreasing not.